# How to create column having values repeated for specific number of times

Tags: sql, excel

Have to create a column next to existing column. my present table is like this

[image: Existing table]

and result needed is like this. Each date value is getting repeated 3 times and getting incremented by 1

[image: Resultant table]

Comment: You can write VBA to do this.

Comment: Using SQL there's no way unless you have another column to order your data. And then it's still a very strange task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick any cell and enter:

```
=DATE(2018,8,21+ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0))
```

and copy downward.

[image]

Here our start cell is one cell to the **left** of the *21*.

Answer (score 0):

Manually type in the first 3 into A1:A3 (or rows 1 to 3) in A4 (or row 4) reference A1 (row 1) and add 1 to it. Then drag the formula down.

The formula should look like `=A1+1`